# Convert Dataframe of dynamic size to numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I want to convert a Pandas data frame to numpy array.I want to perform the operations of transpose,inverse and matrix product.I have something like this,

```
results=pd.read_csv('ed2.txt', sep=',',header=None)
```

Now I want to convert the result to numpy array.When I do 
numpyMatrix = results.as_matrix()
It is giving me values like

```
[  1.00000000e+00   1.60000000e+03   3.00000000e+00]
```

Any solution or suggestions.

Comment: Why you do not use `numpy.loadtext` or `numpy.genfromtxt`?

Comment: That worked.Thanks a lot.I don't know why I was reading it in dataframe.

Comment: You can also use `results.as_matrix()` or `results.values` to convert dataframe into a matrix for future reference.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What's wrong with the values you listed? Maybe you are confused by the scientific notation with `e`? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E-notation The values you listed are `[1 1600 3]`.

Comment: Yes, you are right.I was confused regarding e notation. It was also giving accurate results.I cam to know this later when i had used numpy.loadtext().